# HTML onClick functionality on working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to get images from my server via php and I want to have onClick functionality but it is not working following is my code sample:

```
<?php
$conn = ftp_connect("myserver") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");

$images = ftp_nlist($conn,"folder");
$r = count($images);



for($i=0;$i<$r;$i++)
{   
 //echo "  $images[$i]  ";
echo"<img id= '$i' class = '' border='1'   src='mysource' width='300' height='250'>"; 
echo "<button onClick= 'hide()'> Print </button>";
echo "<button> Email </button>";    
echo "<button> Text Me </button>";
echo "</br>";
}

ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

and following is my javascript code

```
function hide()
  {
    var t = document.getElementById(x); 
    t.setAttribute(class, print);   
     }
```

when I click my print button it is not even calling that function by the way this all is in .php file. Thanks for ay help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the function is not called? Variable x is undefined in your hide(). And class and print?

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here, it would be better if you posted only the received HTML response. However: you might lowercase `onclick`, and in your script there are three undefined variables: `x`, `class`, and `print`. Open your error console and you will see the js engine whinging about it

Comment: Your code sample does not make sense. You are calling javascript:hide() whithout any arguments (hint: try handing over the ID of the element which should be hidden) and also numerical IDs are not allowed in strict (x)html. Also you should look into a JS framework like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

→ **Try This:**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function hide_it(){alert('Entering Function hide_it()?'); /*var t = document.getElementById(x); t.setAttribute(class, print);*/}</script>";

for($i=0;$i<$r;$i++)
{   
     //echo "  $images[$i]  ";
     echo"<img id= '$i' class = '' border='1'   src='mysource' width='300' height='250'>"; 
     echo "<button type='button' onclick='javascript:hide_it()'> Print </button>";
     echo "<button> Email </button>";    
     echo "<button> Text Me </button>";
     echo "</br>";
}
```